# Output comes to be a2a3 instead of a2b3

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

What I understood is that in E object C AND D object are referenced by c and d respectively. But I am not able to understand why d.set_c('b') fail to initialize B.m_c to 'b' where as c.set_n(3) is able to change the value of A.m_n to 3.

```
    #include <iostream>

    class A
    {
    public:
        A(int n = 2) : m_n(n) {}

    public:
        int get_n() const { return m_n; }
        void set_n(int n) { m_n = n; }

    private:
        int m_n;
    };

    class B
    {
    public:
        B(char c = 'a') : m_c(c) {}

    public:
        char get_c() const { return m_c; }
        void set_c(char c) { m_c = c; }

    private:
        char m_c;
    };

    class C
        : virtual public A
        , public B
    { };

    class D
        : virtual public A
        , public B
    { };

    class E
        : public C
        , public D
    { };

    int main()
    {
        E e;  //object of E is created
        C &c = e; //c is used to refrence C object in E Object 
        D &d = e; //c and d has same inheritance structure 
        std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n();

        c.set_n(3);
        d.set_c('b');
        std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n() << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please could you choose a more helpful title?

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at your class structure, if you create an instance of `E`, you will end up with an object hierarchy looking like this:

```
 class B   class A   class B
     \       / \       /
      \     /   \     /
       \   /     \   /
      class C   class D
          \       /
           \     /
            \   /
           class E
```

You see there are two instances of `B`, but only one instance of `A`. This is because of virtual inheritance. Both `C` and `D` inherit from `A` using virtual inheritance, so there is only one instance of `A` in your `e`.

Now lets look at the user code:

```
E e;
C &c = e; // reference C in the object hierarchy of E
D &d = e; // reference D in the object hierarchy of E

c.set_n(3); // set the value in the only instance of A in E
d.set_c('b'); // set the value of one of the two instances of B in your e

std::cout << c.get_c(); // print the value in the other instance of B in e
                        // not the one you set before
std::cout << d.get_n(); // print the value of the only instance of A in e
                        // this got changed before
```

Comment: I've been programming C++ for two years and haven't ever thought about this. You sir, deserve an upvote and a thank you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Objects of class `E` contain `C` and `D` subobjects which in turn each contain a `B` subobject. Since there is no virtual inheritance concerning `B`, each of `C` and `D` *contain their own copy of `B`*.

`d.set_c()` then refers to the `B` contained in `D` and updates that, while `c.get_c()` refers to the `B` contained in `C`, which is independent of the one in `D`, and therefore hasn't changed.

For class `A` and its member `n` there are no such problems because virtual inheritance is used. This makes sure that in the final object of class `E` there is only one subobject `A` that is used by everybody, no matter through which "path" it is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
, public B
```

to

```
, virtual public B
```

to get the output `a2b3`.

In your example, the `E` instance contains to separate `B` instances.